# Storing multiple values in a single column

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2014

I have two columns in my table: [`Employee_id`, `Employee_phno`].

- `Employee_id`: primary key, data type = int
- `Employee_phno`: allows null, data type = int

Now, how can I insert two phone numbers in the same employee_id?

For example:

```
 employee_id employee_phno()

    1        xxxxxxxxx
             yyyyyyyyyy
```

Comment: Its not possible...
try to make composite primary key by combining Employee_Id and Employee phno

Comment: You have to add two separate entries, i.e. two rows, for the same user. Just different phone numbers. Otherwise you need another column for `alternate_phone_number` or something

Answer (score 2):

For me, if you want multiple data for  column `Employee_phno` better make another table for `Employee_phno`. In your second table, set a foreign key as relation for your first table.

Example:

1st table

```
    Employee_id                
         1
         2
         3
```

2nd table

```
  Employee_id   Employee_phno
       1             1234
       2             1512    
       2             4523
```

Here you can see the employee with id = 2 has multiple Employee_phno

Comment: Can you say which key you used for 2nd table employee_id in the  reference with 1st  table employee-id

Comment: @rangeelasunil in the first table, ` Employee_id` is your primary key. Second table, ` Employee_id` is a foreign key. You can create your own primary key for the second table.

Answer (score 0):

It is never possible to insert data in such way in single table.

Comment: any alternative to insert multiple values for a single column

Comment: @rangeelasunil That's how SQL was designed to be used so go ahead and do that. That way you can `select * from tableName where Employee_id = 1`

Comment: @Bhola Ram Saha This does not answer the OP's original question.  If you are going to say no, then say why AND provide some examples.  This is a helping AND learning platform.

Comment: You can use another table for multiple values using Employee_id as reference key.

Comment: @Anthony Horne because value of primary key can not be repeated. Its well known property in any SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If `Employee_id` is primary key then you can have only 1 record for an employee.Since you have only one field for `Employee_phno`,it's not possible to store 2 phone numbers for the same employee.

For doing so, you will have to do any one of the following:

1.Add another column in the data as `Employee_Alternate_phno` and if all the employees won't have 2 numbers you can make this column allow NULLs.

2.Create another mapping table say `EmployeeNumbers` where you will have `EmployeeId` as Foreign key and then the numbers field. Anytime if you want the 2 `Employee_phno` you can do a join on the mapping table and retrieve the values.